# How do I write json content to csv file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am using an api call to request data, which returns JSON.  I need to save this response to a CSV file.

I am able to pull down the JSON response, but am having problems with writing to CSV.

```
# import statements
import json         # package to work with json
import requests     # package to make http requests
import csv

# set global variables
group_id = 0000
api_token = 'yyyy'
api_url = 'https://api.samsara.com/v1'

endpoint_url = api_url + '/fleet/drivers'

# query params for the request
my_params = {"access_token": api_token}

# body data to send with the request
my_data = {"groupId": group_id}

# send POST request to endpoint
resp = requests.post(url = endpoint_url, params = my_params, json = my_data)

# pull out the json
array = resp.json()
text = json.dumps(array)

csvFile = open('/tmp/output.csv','w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
count = 0
for line in text:
    if count == 0:
        header = line.keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csvwriter.writerow(line.values())
csvFile.close()
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get_driver_test4.py", line
>   34, in 
>       header = line.keys() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: What does the JSON look like? Can you share an example?

Comment: Here's an abbreviated version of the JSON..........................................{"drivers": [{"id": 134763, "groupId": 0000, "vehicleId": 212014918234742, "currentVehicleId": 212014918234742, "username": "ablah", "name": "Art Blah"}, {"id": 134764, "groupId": 0000, "vehicleId": 212014918234709, "currentVehicleId": 212014918234709, "username": "btodd", "name": "Barry Todd"}]}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that in order to clarify it. That said, don't use CSV as metaformat if you can use JSON and never mix metaformats, you are only asking for trouble that way. However, that is not your problem here, because you decode the JSON from the response and write that data to CSV (metaformat conversion). Concerning your issues with that, please extract a [mcve] so everyone can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down your problem into different functions like so:

```
import json
import requests
import csv

def get_data():
    group_id = 0000
    api_token = 'yyyy'
    api_url = 'https://api.samsara.com/v1'
    endpoint_url = api_url + '/fleet/drivers'

    my_params = {"access_token": api_token}
    my_data = {"groupId": group_id}
    resp = requests.post(url = endpoint_url, params = my_params, json = my_data)
    array = resp.json()
    text = json.dumps(array)

    return text


def write_file(filename, text):
    dataset = json.loads(text)
    drivers = dataset['drivers']

    csvFile = open(filename,'w')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # write header
    if len(drivers) > 0:
        keys = drivers[0].keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(keys)

    # write data
    for line in drivers:
       csvwriter.writerow(line.values())

    csvFile.close()

text = get_data()
write_file('output.csv', text)
```

That way, you can test your write_file function separate from your get_data function.

One thing to be careful about is GroupID of `0000`. If you have group id typed like that, you may get a JSON parsing error. If you really want 4 character numbers, find a way to quote them like `"0000"`. If you are just interested in number, replace `0000` with `0`.

To test your theory, at the bottom of the python file just use something like this:

```
text = '{"drivers": [{"id": 134763, "groupId": "0000", "vehicleId": 212014918234742, "currentVehicleId": 212014918234742, "username": "ablah", "name": "Art Blah"}, {"id": 134764, "groupId": "0000", "vehicleId": 212014918234709, "currentVehicleId": 212014918234709, "username": "btodd", "name": "Barry Todd"}]}'
write_file('output.csv', text)
```

**Resulting file**

```
id,groupId,vehicleId,currentVehicleId,username,name
134763,0000,212014918234742,212014918234742,ablah,Art Blah
134764,0000,212014918234709,212014918234709,btodd,Barry Todd
```

Comment: Thanks very much @zedfoxus.  Your solution is perfect!

Comment: I would recommend using "newline=''" to avoid unwanted blank lines when writing the file ( => open(filename,'w', newline='')), but thank you anyway for the nice working example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what about this:

```
# import statements
import json         # package to work with json
import requests     # package to make http requests
import csv
resp = """
{
    "drivers":[
        {
            "id":134763,
            "groupId":1234,
            "vehicleId":212014918234742,
            "currentVehicleId":212014918234742,
            "username":"ablah",
            "name":"Art Blah"
        },
        {
            "id":134764,
            "groupId":1234,
            "vehicleId":212014918234709,
            "currentVehicleId":212014918234709,
            "username":"btodd",
            "name":"Barry Todd"
        }
    ]
}
"""
text = json.loads(resp)
csvFile = open('output.csv','w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
line = text["drivers"]
csvwriter.writerow(["id","groupId","vehicleId","currentVehicleId","username","name"])
for l in line:
    csvwriter.writerow([l["id"],l["groupId"],l["vehicleId"],l["currentVehicleId"],l["username"],l["name"]])
    
    
csvFile.close()
```

You can adjust the code to fit your needs.

Output.csv

```
id,groupId,vehicleId,currentVehicleId,username,name

134763,1234,212014918234742,212014918234742,ablah,Art Blah

134764,1234,212014918234709,212014918234709,btodd,Barry Todd
```

By the way...

In the sample json you gave, the groupId 0000 throws an error in python, as it's not a valid number. Consider making 0000 a string "0000"

More references...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html